# JavaScript and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" onclick="timeTracker._recordStartTime();" value="" dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="FirstName"/>
<br /> <br /><br /><br />
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="continue1" onclick="timeTracker._recordEndTime(); timeTracker._track(pageTracker, 'CatagoryName', 'Writing FIrst Name ');" iconClass="dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconRedo" type="button" style="float:right">
                            Continue
```

using this GA time tracker I can record the start and stop times of the event as well as the event category and event label. Now I also want to get the `FirstName` input from a user and associate it with this recorded event.

Any idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onclick="timeTracker._recordEndTime(); timeTracker._track(pageTracker, 'CatagoryName', document.getElementById('FirstName').value);"
```

Comment: Thanx Diodeus !I tried this but cannot get the entry of FirstName from the user send to GA